# Java comma separated value in object need to add it as two records in the list

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-8

I have on object with few keys have comma separted value and i wanted to add it as next record in the list:

```
Response Object:
{
record:1,2
record1:234,123
record2:Mx,Fx
recoddate:08/12/2021
recodenddate:08/13/2021
}
```

i wanted to keep it two object records as below

```
{
record:1
record1:234
record2:Mx
recoddate:08/12/2021
recodenddate:08/13/2021
},
{record:2
record1:123
record2:Fx
recoddate:08/12/2021
recodenddate:08/13/2021
}
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the fields in `Response` should be split into separate values (assuming the fields are strings) and then new objects are created assuming a constructor/builder exists in `Record` class, which are collected then into list:

```java
String[] parts  = response.getRecord().split(",");
String[] parts1 = response.getRecord1().split(",");
String[] parts2 = response.getRecord2().split(",");

List<Record> records = IntStream.range(0, Math.max(parts.length, Math.max(parts1.length, parts2.length)))
        .mapToObj(i -> new Record(
            i < part.length  ? part[i]  : "",
            i < part1.length ? part1[i] : "",
            i < part2.length ? part2[i] : "",
            response.getRecordDate(),
            response.getRecordEndDate()
        ))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```